# ODBC array fetch of VARBINARY column causes server timeout

Tags: php, sql-server, timeout, odbc

I have an app that fetches a `VARBINARY(max)` data from SQL Server database. On my local environment the app connects via SQL Driver. Connection string of `odbc_connect` contains:

```
DRIVER={SQL Server}
```

I am fetching the VARBINARY data like this:

```
// Hexadecimal data of attachment
$query = 'SELECT * FROM attachments WHERE LOC_BLOB_ID = ' . $blob_id;
$attach_result = odbc_exec($connection, $query);
odbc_binmode($attach_result, ODBC_BINMODE_CONVERT);
odbc_longreadlen ($attach_result, 262144);
$attach_row = odbc_fetch_array($attach_result);
$hex_data = $attach_row['attachment_value'];
$binary = hex2bin($hex_data);
```

It works well. Now I need to run this app on a server where my only option is to use the ODBC driver 17 for SQL Server. Connection string contains:

```
DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}
```

And it doesn't work. It fails on line number 6 of the preview above (on `odbc_fetch_array`). I've tried commenting out the `odbc_binmode` and `odbc_longreadlen` lines (I assumed this driver might handle those data natively), but no luck, same result: Service unavailable timeout error.

Is there a different approach to this width ODBC Driver 17?

**Edit:** I found out it hangs on `ODBC_BINMODE_CONVERT`. If I change it to `ODBC_BINMODE_RETURN`, it runs within few seconds - however the output is wrong. The `ODBC_BINMODE_CONVERT` is indeed what I need, but it doesn't process the entire data in time (the timeout is 30 seconds), which is strange, because the VARBINARY field in the database is only 65K characters long, and it runs extremely fast on my local environment.

***Edit2:** I've tried to convert the incomplete binary data fetched from the database to hexadecimal and then to PNG and it displays half of the image. So I am positive it is fetching the correct data, it just takes incredibly long to fetch that column, resulting in timeouts in almost every case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Finaly figured it out. What ended up working for me was using `ODBC_BINMODE_RETURN` flag instead of `ODBC_BINMODE_CONVERT`, and **NOT** using `hex2bin()` conversion at the end.

The code in my original question worked fine with `{SQL Server}`, and the following code works with `{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}`:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM attachments WHERE LOC_BLOB_ID = ' . $blob_id;
$attach_result = odbc_exec($connection, $query);
odbc_binmode($attach_result, ODBC_BINMODE_RETURN);
odbc_longreadlen ($attach_result, 262144);
$attach_row = odbc_fetch_array($attach_result);
$binary = $attach_row['attachment_value'];
```